# Change Connection String dynamically to create database and store the created file in specific folder

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, database-connection

I want to connect SQL server database for my application. I want to provide two types of authentication one is windows authentication and other is Sql server authentication. I tried by the below code. but, I was confused where my file is actually stored.

Model:

```
 public class DataBase : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DatabaseType DatabaseType { get; set; }

    private AuthenticationType authenticationType;

    public AuthenticationType AuthenticationType
    {
        get { return authenticationType; }
        set
        {
            authenticationType = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AuthenticationType);
        }
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

For Authentication:

```
public void WindowsAuthentication(DataBase dataBase)
    {
        TaskContext = new TaskContext(dataBase.Name);
        Tasks = GetAll();
    }

    public void ServerAuthentication(DataBase dataBase)
    {
        ConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source=.; User Id={0};Password={1};", dataBase.UserName, dataBase.Password);
        try
        {
            SqlHelper = new SqlHelper(ConnectionString);
            if (SqlHelper.IsConnection)
            {
                //AppSetting appSetting = new AppSetting();
                //appSetting.SaveConnectionString("DbConnect", ConnectionString);
                TaskContext = new TaskContext(ConnectionString);
                Tasks = GetAll();
                MessageBox.Show("Conected Successfully");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Sql Server Connection Check:

```
 public class SqlHelper
{
    SqlConnection SqlConnection;

    public SqlHelper(String connectionString)
    {
        SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public bool IsConnection
    {
        get
        {
            if (SqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                SqlConnection.Open();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

EF Code:

```
 public class TaskContext : DbContext
{
    public TaskContext(string connection) : base(connection)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TaskContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

Help me in creation of database and using EF approach and to store in the specific folder

Comment: The default files go in the c:\Program Files folder.  You can use SQL Server Management Studio to check exact location by right clicking on a Database and select Properties : Files.

Comment: Depending on which database server you use (SQLExpress, SQLServer, MySql etc etc), the files could be located in many different places.  You don't state which SQL server you are using, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Using SQL Server and How to give connection string for Windows authentication and for Sql server Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has no control over where the file will be located, SQL Server has that control. All you can do is use a connection string to specify the server (IP address) and database name.

You can find the location by using Sql Management Server, but that doesn't mean you can control it once you have that knowledge.

The default is to store the database file in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Sql Server` but that is only the default (and could be different depending on which version of SQL server you are running).